# Devise flash messages not model errors when logging in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

Why does devise set flash messages instead of model errors when logging in? I would expect model errors given its failing validations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which field would you like to place the error on? Authentication errors are on a combination of email and password fields. If you put it on the email address, the user will get confused if they've entered their email address correctly, but they entered their password wrong.

Also, if you look up the user by email and then try to validate their password, so you can at least put an error address on the email if it's incorrect - well, if some random person comes along to your site trying to guess e-mail addresses, you've just told them if someone else's email address is in the system or not.

Answer (score 0):

The user isn't going to know much about models, etc.  A nice flash message at the top that says "Invalid email or password." or whatever the problem is (in plain language) sounds more neutral and is less intimidating than something like "Password can't be blank."  At least in theory...